# mapping win32_logicaldisk to win32_diskdrive?

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, command-line-interface, flash-cs5

i am building an Adobe Air App where i can only fetch the "drive letter" of the particular usb thumb drive i am plugging in.

This drive can be easily also fetched with `wmic logicaldisk where 'DeviceId="D:"'` if drive letter is `D:`

But what i really want is to get the PNPDeviceID of Win32_DiskDrive class for the drive mentioned before.

As far as i can think , linking win32_logicaldisk and win32_diskdrive with some class in between would do the trick , yet i can't figure the way for it.

So i kindly request to put your expertise forward on this thread to solve this problem.

cheers

SJ

Comment: Windows doesn't have a one-to-one mapping of "disks" and USB devices. A USB device may have zero disks (e.g. mouse ;) ) or two (partitioned USB disk).

Comment: you are right , what i am interested in is mapping a drive letter coming from Win32_LogicalDisk to it's PNPDeviceID which is coming from Win32_DiskDrive class.

So i can easily get the PNPDeviceID of the USB Drive (aka Hardware UID) with it's mounted drive letter.

That is what i am trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Answer from here http://forum.exetools.com/showthread.php?t=11226

WMIC PATH WIN32_DISKPARTITION ASSOC <-- this command links win32_logicaldisk with win32_diskdrive in a weird but manageable way.

thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need two different WMI classes to derive this. First, [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394175.aspx), to (obviously enough) map the logical disk to a partition. Then you can use [`Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394134.aspx) to find the physical drive holding that partition.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply , but those two classes (LogicalDiskToPartition and DiskDriveToDiskPartition) contains no information to link with either Win32_LogicalDisk or Win32_DiskDrive. So that is not a good way to proceed :(

Comment: @SupunJ The Antecedent/Dependent properties of each of those classes  contains links to the DeviceId properties of Win32_LogicalDrive, Win32_DiskPartition and Win32_DiskDrive objects and form a logical connection between the three.